# Execute multiple map iterators in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I want to understand once concept related to the map iterator in javascript. I want to execute multiple map iterator and I have came up with the below solution.

```
await Promise.all({
    arrOne.map(async first => {
         arrTwo = //call another await operation
        arrTwo.map(async second => {
            arrThree = //call another await operation
            arrThree.map(async third => {
                //return await operation and result
            })
        })
    })
})
```

What I want to achieve is to process the data in the parallel approach which I think through Promise.all we can achieve. I want to know if this is the good approach.

Also I want to process a large dataset. Will the above approach works because I was also thinking to process the data in batches.

Comment: I don't think it's a good approach but it should be able to work. However, I need to add others `Promise.all` to all your async map.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I was thinking to chain them and then execute them finally in Promise.all

Comment: @Hao-JungHsieh I will chain the map operations add Promise.all and finally execute them then in Promise.all. I think this will be a better solution.

Comment: *"I wil chain the map operations"*: this is not visible in your code. Can you include the code that shows *how* you chain them?

Answer (score 0):

Never try this but I think you need something like:

```js
await Promise.all(
    arrOne.map(async lvl1 => {
        return await Promise.all(
            lvl1.map(async lvl2 => {
                return await Promise.all(
                    lvl2.map(async lvl3 => {
                        return await Promise.all(lvl3 => [lvl3 || 'something']);
                    })
                );
            })
        );
    })
);
```

`Promise.all` in each array of iterable.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to process tasks in the parallel approach, you should do `Promise.all` with pass tasks value as an array like this :

```js
Promise.all([ task1(), task2(), task3(), ... ]);
```

The task is represented in the form of a function that can be filled with any command including the map iterator. For example :

```js
let httpRequest = (method, theUrl) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      type: method,
      url: theUrl,
      success: (res)=>{
        resolve(res);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  }); 
}

let getTime = () => {
  return (new Date()).toISOString().replace('T',' ').replace('Z','');
}

(async() => {
  await Promise.all([
    (async () => {
      console.log('arrOne start:',getTime());
      let arrOne = (await httpRequest('GET', 'https://dummyjson.com/products')).products;
      arrOne = arrOne.map(arr => `${arr.id} ${arr.title}`);
      console.log('arrOne finish:',getTime());
      return arrOne;
    })(), (async () => {
      console.log('arrTwo start:',getTime());
      let arrTwo = (await httpRequest('GET', 'https://dummyjson.com/carts')).carts;
      arrTwo = arrTwo.map(arr => `${arr.id} ${arr.products[0].title}`);
      console.log('arrTwo finish:',getTime());
      return arrTwo;
    })(), (async () => {
      console.log('arrThree start:',getTime());
      let arrThree = (await httpRequest('GET', 'https://dummyjson.com/users')).users;
      arrThree = arrThree.map(arr => `${arr.id} ${arr.firstName}`);
      console.log('arrThree finish:',getTime());
      return arrThree;
    })()
  ]).then((res)=>{
    console.log('arrOne:\n',res[0]);
    console.log('arrTwo:\n',res[1]);
    console.log('arrThree:\n',res[2]);
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not the type of nesting the Asker needs. Their `arrOne` needs to be iterated in order to produce an `arrTwo` for **each** entry in `arrOne`, ...etc.